# How to find files not accessed for the period of time without atime in linux?

Tags: linux

Is there a way in the linux to find files which were accessed (read, write, doesn't matter) during computer boot and work? Or even better files that were NOT accessed at all during some time? I know there is a `find / -atime +60` (for example for older than 60 days files) command, but problem is that in this system the modification of atime attribute for files is disabled as it works from flashcard. So i need some other way to find those files.

Comment: Consider accepting correct answers to your questions. Also, upvote useful answers.

Comment: Sure i will. I can't upvote answers yet, system doesn't allow it for me.

Answer (score 1):

For files accessed during boot, I'd start with [ureadahead](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/ureadahead.8.html):

```
$ sudo ureadahead --dump | grep /
```

which dumps the content of `/var/lib/ureadahead/pack` where the profiled boot file accesses are stored.

Otherwise there are lots of ways to monitor file access:

- [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/), see [monitoring file and directory access on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205815/monitoring-file-and-directory-access-on-linux)
- [loggedfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18844/list-the-files-accessed-by-a-program), but might be tricky to setup at boot time.
- [fatrace](https://launchpad.net/fatrace), report system wide file access events.
- [auditctl](http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditctl) probably as well.

[bootchart](http://www.bootchart.org/) might be helpful to visualize what's happening during boot.